# Targetframework error when deploying MVC 4.5.1 on my server that has 4.0.3 installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

My windows server 2008 R2 has .NET framework v4.0.3x installed currently.

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4.5.1 application that when I deploy I get the following error:

```
The 'targetFramework' attribute in the <compilation> element of the Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example, '<compilation targetFramework="4.0">'). The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework.

Source Error: 


Line 37:   </appSettings>
Line 38:   <system.web>
Line 39:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
Line 40:     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
Line 41:     <pages>
```

Do I need to install something on the server or is it an issue of my not deploying the correct dll's in my /bin folder?

I have IIS 7.5.7x installed.

Comment: I believe this has been solved, so either you accept the answer below or post/accept your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the current .Net Framework on your server. After this it should work since IIS makes no difference between 4.0 and 4.5. Additionally you need to select the correct target framework in the IIS administration.

[This](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/03/upgrade-to-net-4-unrecognized-attribute.html) is how its done.

Comment: Hi, where is the link that I need to install?  I have already set my application pool to use 4.x.